# How can we demonstrate that we are the right Islam?

Tags: sharia, practical-islam, islamic-basis

In many places around the World Islam represent terrorism and bad actions.
That's why many Non-Muslims believe that Islam is a religion of bad things.
Now what comes to my mind, is that we believe we are the right Islam, while them are just bad people, yet they firmly believe they are doing right things because Islam say so.
How can we be so sure that we are practicing islam in the right way? Maybe ISIS and Islamic states are practicing it in the right way! Is it really Islam that make us thing we are right or simply our coscience and moral?

Comment: This is a highly opinion-based question; obviously every interpretation of Islam would have their own reasons for insisting that *theirs* is "the right Islam". As written, this question is unlikely to attract actual *useful* answers rather than just instigate argument and debate (which is not what this site is for: see http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22)

Comment: I dont think it is! Don't you always say that Islam is ONE, and there is no opinion? You always say that People cannot say I'm muslim yet do things that they feel are right to do even if some other muslims think it's a Sin. Doesn't this mean that I can decided whether do a thing or  not, or whether follow a thing or not becuase I interpret it that way? If Qu'ran is One, there shoudnt be different opinions.......Or in that case, People should be totally free to have different opinions on it!

Comment: @Jule hm... Islam is one, but the interpretations of Islam are many- and not all of them are totally wrong! And depending on the environment, education, situation etc. one grows up he/she takes the for him/her convenient interpretation as it seems forgetting that you can't do only Jihad and forget to pray or the akhlaq or only concentrate on prayers or the Quran or the appearance and neglect other parts. Islam should taken as a whole! unfortunatly those who represent, speak out or come forward to speak for islam are mostly not those who see it as a whole religion with every single part of it!

Comment: Jule! I want to clarify what you are asking. Do you mean that how will we know Islam is the true religion while others aren't? Or do you mean how will I know that I am practicing correct sect of Islam or not!